# How to switch between 12 and 24-hour time in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, clock, nexus-4

I recently installed the latest stable build of Ubuntu Touch on my Galaxy Nexus 4. Runs great! But I can't figure out how to change the time from 12-hour am/pm to 24-hour.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a [missing feature](http://pad.lv/1388931) till now. It is supposed to be fixed with upcoming OTA-13 update. As a bad workaround you may try switching the **display language** (UK English shows 24-hour clock, while US English shows 12-hour clock as I remember).

Comment: Sweet, I'll wait for the OTA-13 update, then. Thanks pomsky.